# Thunderbird printing: How to shrink images to fit page without shrinking text?

Tags: printing, thunderbird

When I print an email in Thunderbird and choose the *Scale* Option **Shrink to Fit** (on the Print Preview screen) it shrinks large images down so that they fit to the width of the page, but at the same time it shrinks the text proportionally.  I end up with a printout with ridiculously small text.  This is a strange implementation, in my opinion, since text will automatically wrap as needed anyway.  What I would like to do is have any images too large to fit on the page be shrunk, but leave the text the same size it would be if the *Scale* option was set to **100%**.

I ran into this issue on a previous machine, and after a fair amount of searching I found that I could achieve what I wanted by changing a setting in the Config Editor.  Unfortunately, I've since lost the bookmark to the page that named the setting.  I've been searching via Google as well as this forum all morning but I haven't been able to come across the answer again.  Does anyone know of the setting in the Config Editor that I'm talking about, or another solution to only shrink images when printing?

**EDIT:** My current version of Thunderbird is 24.4.0, O/S is Windows 7 Pro SP1.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of your previous machine, you could search for prefs.js under profiles, in there the settings from the config editor are stored. On my machine, it is under C:\Documents and Settings\ -username-\Application Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\yeyuzlt5.default

Comment: That's a good point, however the backup of that profile no longer exists. And I probably copied over the mail but not the prefs during the migration. It looks like I'll be forced to use Outlook at work soon anyway, so I guess it won't matter to me much longer. At least printing is the one thing Microsoft software seems to do reliably.